# Excel VBA UserForm Tag Property

Tags: excel, vba, tags

I have a UserForm with Text and Combo Boxes, some of which represent "REQUIRED FIELDS" and cannot be left blank. I have entered the value RQD for the tag property of the target controls. My objective is to loop through the controls and use their Tag property to identify controls that cannot be empty (where Tag property value = RQD) and change their BackColor property if they are. However, I cannot get this work. Below is some of the code:-

```
With frm_RecCapture
    '
    .lbl01_RecDate = Format(Date, "Long Date", vbSunday)
    .txt01_RecNum = Format(RecNum, "000000")
    .txt01_RecNum.Enabled = False
    .txt01_AccNum.SetFocus
    '
    frmComplete = False
    .Show
    '
    Do While frmComplete = False
        .Show
        '
        For Each frmCtrl In .Controls
            If TypeName(frmCtrl) = "Textbox" Or TypeName(frmCtrl) = "Combobox" Then
                If frmCtrl.Tag = "RQD" And frmCtrl.Text = "" Then
                    frmCtrl.BackColor = &HFFFF&
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next frmCtrl
        '
        If n = 0 Then
            frmComplete = True
        Else
            frmComplete = False
            MsgBox "ERROR! Fields highlighted in yellow cannot be left blank. Please "
            complete these fields before continuing.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, SysTitle
        End If
    Loop
    '
End With
```

Any suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: Apologies for the way the code is presented in my post. I'm new to stack overflow and don't yet know how to retain code in its original format in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer writing a class that wraps and validates a control.  You will need to store a reference to the wrapper class in a collection of some type of class level variable keep it from falling out of scope.

### Class: RequiredFieldControl

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents ComboBox  As MSForms.ComboBox
Private WithEvents TextBox  As MSForms.TextBox
Private mControl  As MSForms.Control

Private Const DefaultBackColor As Long = -2147483643
Private Const InvalidBackColor As Long = vbYellow ' &HFFFF&

Public Property Set Control(ByVal Value As MSForms.Control)
    Set mControl = Value
    Select Case TypeName(Control)
        Case "ComboBox"
            Set ComboBox = Value
        Case "TextBox"
            Set TextBox = Value
    End Select
    FormatControl
End Property

Public Property Get Control() As MSForms.Control
    Set Control = mControl
End Property

Sub FormatControl()
    Control.BackColor = IIf(isValid, DefaultBackColor, InvalidBackColor)
End Sub

Public Function isValid() As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(Control)
        Case "ComboBox"
            isValid = ComboBox.ListIndex > -1
        Case "TextBox"
            isValid = Len(TextBox.Value) > 0
    End Select
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
    FormatControl
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    FormatControl
End Sub
```

### Form Code

```
Private RequiredFields As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set RequiredFields = New Collection
    AddRequiredFields Me.Controls
    ComboBox1.List = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    Debug.Print RequiredFields.Count
End Sub

Sub AddRequiredFields(pControls As MSForms.Controls)
    Dim RequiredField As RequiredFieldControl
    Dim Control As MSForms.Control
    For Each Control In pControls
        If Control.Tag = "RQD" Then
            Select Case TypeName(Control)
                Case "ComboBox", "TextBox"
                    Set RequiredField = New RequiredFieldControl
                    Set RequiredField.Control = Control
                    RequiredFields.Add RequiredField
            End Select
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            AddRequiredFields Control.Controls
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
       
    Next
End Sub

Function AreAllRequiredFieldsFilled() As Boolean
    Dim RequiredField As RequiredFieldControl
    For Each RequiredField In RequiredFields
        If Not RequiredField.isValid Then Exit Function
    Next
    AreAllRequiredFieldsFilled = True
End Function
```